# Microsoft Graph authentication problem when switching to Client Secret: the scope is not valid

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

My first Microsoft Graph application, meant to download email attachments of a service mail box, used the `DeviceCodeCredential` authentication class like in the following code:

```
var credentials = new DeviceCodeCredential(        
      (info, cancel) => { Console.WriteLine(info.Message); return Task.FromResult(0); },
      "12345678-1234-1234-1234-12345678" /*TenantId*/,
      "99999999-9999-9999-9999-999999999999" /*ClientID*/
      );
```

We provided the credentials to the `GraphServiceClient` constructor; this works just fine, that is we can enumerate the items in the mailbox and download the attachments (code for those operations not included since it's not relevant to the problem).

```
var graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(
                             credentials, 
                             new string [] {"Mail.Read", "Mail.ReadBasic", "Mail.ReadWrite"});
```

Then we switched to client secret authentication; we generated a client secret for that app and changed the credential object to a `ClentSecretCredential` object with the following code:

```
var credentials = new ClientSecretCredential("12345678-1234-1234-1234-12345678" /*TenantId*/, 
                                             "99999999-9999-9999-9999-999999999999" /*ClientID*/,
                                             "SOME8SECRET123GENERATEDBYAZURE" /*Client Secret*/);
```

Now, when we call the very same `GraphServiceClient` constructor, we get the exception:

> Azure.Identity.AuthenticationFailedException: ClientSecretCredential
> authentication failed: AADSTS1002012: The provided value for scope
> Mail.Read Mail.ReadBasic Mail.ReadWrite is not valid. Client
> credential flows must have a scope value with /.default suffixed to
> the resource identifier (application ID URI).

Seems like there is more to change to switch from an authentication schema to the other. But what exactly?

Comment: Credentials and Authentication aren't the same.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?force_isolation=true&view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Client Credential flows, the value for `scopes` in `GraphServiceClient` should be `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`

See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#get-a-token) for client credentials flow

| Parameter | Description |
| --- | --- |
| Scope | The value passed for the scope parameter in this request should be the resource identifier (application ID URI) of the resource you want, affixed with the .default suffix. For the Microsoft Graph example, the value is https://graph.microsoft.com/.default. This value tells the Microsoft identity platform that of all the direct application permissions you have configured for your app, the endpoint should issue a token for the ones associated with the resource you want to use. To learn more about the /.default scope, see the consent documentation |